# Compilation error when using expression in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have some linq query like

```
  Expression<Func<sometable, bool>> whereClauseDynamic= t => true;

 if (#somecondition)
        whereClauseDynamic= t => t.ID == #somevalue;

 var temp= (from tax in db.sometable
              join x in db.y on #someid
              where trans.Finished >= start
              where trans.Finished <= end
              where whereClauseDynamic
               .................
```

This works fine if i use Entity Framework type syntax

```
(from t in db.sometable
           .Where(t => t.Finished >= start)
           .Where(whereClauseLocation)
            .................
```

But throws a compilation error in 1st case

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'bool'
>
> Error CS1662 Cannot convert query expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

One dirty trick is to use a default (always true) Expression for every table in the query. And based on the condition you have, you change one (or more) of them to a real where clause. In your query, you apply them all by default.

```
Expression<Func<X, bool>> whereClauseDynamicX = t => true;
Expression<Func<Y, bool>> whereClauseDynamicY = t => true;
Expression<Func<Z, bool>> whereClauseDynamicZ = t => true;
Expression<Func<someTable, bool>> whereClauseDynamicSomeTable = t => true;


from tax in db.sometable.Where(whereClauseDynamicSomeTable )
join x in db.x.Where(whereClauseDynamicX) on #someid
/* Continue the query */
```

### Another way:

Build your query on the way with the conditions, meaning:

```
IQueryable<someTable> someTableQuery = db.sometable;
IQueryable<X> xQuery = db.x;
IQueryable<Y> yQuery = db.y;
IQueryable<Z> zQuery = db.z;

if(condition1)
    someTableQuery = someTableQuery.Where(x=> /* some condition */)
//.
//.
//.


var query = from tax in someTableQuery
            join x in xQuery
            /* REST */
```

The above approaches have not negative effect of performance whatsoever, because the query is only executed when Enumerated (using a loop or other methods like `ToList()` -  `ToArray()`)

Comment: what is my where condition is not derived from #sometable i.e. first table but is dependent upon table which is getting joined say x in this case

Comment: @AnshulNigam But you specified the type to be `Expression<Func<sometable, bool>>`

Comment: my bad, i changed it now

Comment: It works but will it affect the rows which will be joined?

Comment: @AnshulNigam Absolutely Not. If you apply a where clause then yes the joined table is filtered. If the default of true, then it will not affect it. It is even discarded in most providers.